# Efficient Classification of records by common letters in impala

Tags: sql, regex, impala, dense-rank

I have a table in impala (`TBL1`), that contains different names with different number of first common letters. The table contains about 3M records. I would like to add add an new attribute to the table, where each common first letters will have a class. It is the same way as `DENSE_RANK` work but with dynamic number of first letters. The number of same first letters should not be less than `p=3` letters (`p` = parameter).
Here is an example for the table and the required results:

```
|  ID   |   Attr1      | New_Attr1   | Some more attribute...
+-------+--------------+-------------+-----------------------
|  1    | ZXA-12       |  1          |
|  2    | YL3300       |  2          |
|  3    | ZXA-123      |  1          |
|  4    | YL3400       |  2          |
|  5    | YL3-aaa      |  2          |
|  6    | TSA 789      |  3          |
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by strleft(attr1, 3)) as newcol
from . . .;
```

The "3" is your parameter.

As a note:  In your example, you seem to have assigned the new value in reverse alphabetic order.  Hence, you would want `desc` for the `order by`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to keep the table order as is. Does it change because of the order by?

Comment: The alphabetic order was just an example and must not be in real case.

Comment: @Avi . . . Add `order by id` to the query.